# How to call a knockout method with a parameter in select menu changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm new in Knockout. 
I have 2 dropdown list. The first one is for states' names that is populated in HTML. 
The second one is for cities, which will be populated by a method in Knockout.js that have a ajax call to populate the cities list depending on the selected state. This method will be called on change in state dropdown.

I know that we can call a method on change in this way:

```
<select id="state" name="state" data-bind="event: {change: getCities}">
```

However, I want to pass the selected state value to the getCities method. How I can do that?

I tried:

```
<select id="state" name="state" data-bind="event: {change: getCities(this.value)}">
```

but it does not work. It just pollutes the cities of the default selected menu. The **"this.value"** is send as **undefined**. 
How I can pass the new selected state value to the method?

Comment: well you need to have a `value` binding on select element like `value:selectedState`. then upon change you can pass `getCities(selectedState)` . but passing inLine via `event` not a great way try subscribing to `value` binded observable and access the selectedValue there .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can attach an observable to select element that will hold the current selectedValue and then `subscribe` to changes of this observable. Something like this

```
function vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.state = ko.observable()

  self.getCities = function(stateVal){
    console.log("getCities called with ",stateVal)
  }

  self.state.subscribe(function(stateVal){
    self.getCities(stateVal)
  })

}
ko.applyBindings(new vm())
```

with html

```
<select id="state" name="state" data-bind="value: state">
<option value="1">state 1</option>
<option value="2">state 2</option>
<option value="3">state 3</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/newuserjs/dmq52ycu/